# shift One column values to Another while retrieving results

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have 2 Tables

usermaster

```
ID  UserType    UserName    
1   SuperAdmin  SAdmin
```

and ProfessorMaster

```
Id  UserName    AdminID 
2   Myname  2   Myname
```

I want to Combine UserName of both table in One Column where retrieving Results . I am using Query

```
select  P.UserName,A.UserName from ProfessorMaster P inner join usermaster A on A.ID=P.AdminID where P.IsSelected=1
```

I am getting record like this

```
UserName    UserName1
Myname  Admin
prof    Professor
Prof12  Admin
```

But I want this

```
UserName    

Myname  
prof    
Prof12  
Admin
Professor
```

How can I Achieve this ?

Comment: You need to use UNION to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union` to get it into one column.

```
select P.UserName as username 
from ProfessorMaster P inner join usermaster A 
on A.ID=P.AdminID 
where P.IsSelected=1 
union
select A.UserName
from ProfessorMaster P inner join usermaster A 
on A.ID=P.AdminID 
where P.IsSelected=1
```